# Treating an Array of (String, Int) Tuples like a Dictionary

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of tuples that looks like the following:

```
(("String1", Value1), ("String2", Value2), ...)
```

Where string is a `String` and value is a `Double`. Is there a method in scala to accomplish the following:

1) Search the list for a particular string value.

2) If we have a hit, return the value associated with the string.

3) If we have a miss, return -1.

This tuple sequence was created using `collect` on an RDD of format RDD[K, V] where the keys were strings and the vals were the doubles. Originally I planned on using lookup on the RDD, but it appears that this work needs to be done on the driver (hence the `collect`).

Comment: Use `collectAsMap` instead of `collect` http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@collectAsMap():scala.collection.Map[K,V]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to convert it to a map first then:

```
scala> val collection = Map(("hello", 1), ("world", 2))
collection: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(hello -> 1, world -> 2)

scala> collection getOrElse ("hello", -1)
res3: Int = 1

scala> collection getOrElse ("scala", -1)
res4: Int = -1
```

Comment: Ended up converting it to a map, as you both suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
val m = list.toMap.withDefaultValue(-1d)

// 1 and 2
m("String1") // Value1

// 3
m("Some other") // -1d
```